# CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9805) in iOS 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ssl, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to HTTP POST to a server using Alamofire (a Swift library for networking, https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) and I'm getting the following error when doing a HTTP POST:

`2015-01-05 19:37:07.137 PIPiOS[1021:26574] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9805)
2015-01-05 19:37:07.540 PIPiOS[1021:26574] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9805)
2015-01-05 19:37:07.942 PIPiOS[1021:26574] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed (-9805)
2015-01-05 19:37:07.943 PIPiOS[1021:26574] NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9805)
<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7f99425177c0> { URL: https://kmis.brookes.ac.uk/csms/w_secure.login }
nil
Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1200 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1200.)" UserInfo=0x7f9944859110 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://kmis.brookes.ac.uk/csms/w_secure.login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://kmis.brookes.ac.uk/csms/w_secure.login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9805, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f994259f3c0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1200.)"})
2015-01-05 19:38:25.115 Oxford Brookes[1021:27197] Terminating since there is no system app.`

I was previously using the SwiftHTTP library and getting the same error. HTTP POST works fine through Java and PHP so I know there isn't anything wrong with the server. Any idea why this is happening?

PS: I'm testing on iOS Simulator targeting iOS 8.1, and yes I've checked date/time and it's fine

Comment: For people searching, here's a list of error codes relating to the ssl handshake: http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libsecurity_ssl/libsecurity_ssl-32463/lib/SecureTransport.h

Answer (score 1):

The server has a broken configuration. It does not support the common and most compatible SSLv23 handshake but only supports explicit TLSv1 and SSLv3 handshakes. Browser work around this kind of problems by trying different handshakes, but other application don't do such workarounds. You might have a look at [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=kmis.brookes.ac.uk) to see how badly this server is configured.

I'm not an apple developer but from the documentation I guess you need to play around with SSLSetProtocolVersion* functions to enforce TLS1.0 or SSL3.0 connections.

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding the SSL security policy. Check in your framework API you will find some property to do that.
As I found in while working on AFnetworking.

```
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = YES;
```

Hope it helps.

Also you can try  in this way 
Normally when I get CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed -(*) Its because of my local wifi network (device is connected to network but not the internet)

Try it again on another network (3G is the quickest solution for me)